# Ruby encryption program giving me mixed results

Tags: ruby

I wrote this program to take a name, reverse the first and last name, and move the letters over by one. When I run it, it runs fine, except that at the end it spits out each name with an alias of every other name's aliases. They seem to be exponential, if I have three aliases, I get nine results. Please help me. New to ruby.

```
@aliases = [] 
@real = []

def alias_machine(name)
@real << name
name = name.downcase
name_array = name.split(' ')
first_name = name_array[1]
first_name_split = first_name.split('')
last_name = name_array[0]
new_namearray1 = first_name_split.map do |y|
vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
    if y == vowels[0]
        y = "e"
    elsif y == vowels[1]
        y = "i"
    elsif y == vowels[2]
        y = "o"
    elsif y == vowels[3]
        y = "u"
    elsif y == vowels[4]
        y = "a"
    elsif y.next == "aa"
        y = "b"
    elsif y.next == vowels[1] 
        y = y.next.next
    elsif y.next == vowels[2] 
        y = y.next.next
    elsif y.next == vowels[3] 
        y = y.next.next
    elsif y.next == vowels[4] 
        y = y.next.next
    else 
        y = y.next
    end
end
last_name_split = last_name.split('')
new_namearray2 = last_name_split.map do |y|  
    vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
if y == vowels[0]
    y = "e"
elsif y == vowels[1]
    y = "i"
elsif y == vowels[2]
    y = "o"
elsif y == vowels[3]
    y = "u"
elsif y == vowels[4]
    y = "a"
elsif y.next == "aa"
    y = "b"
elsif y.next == vowels[1] 
    y = y.next.next
elsif y == vowels[2]
     y.next.next
elsif y.next == vowels[3] 
    y = y.next.next
elsif y.next == vowels[4]
    y= y.next.next
else 
y = y.next 
end
end


new_namearray1 = new_namearray1.join('')
new_namearray1 = new_namearray1 + " "
new_namearray1 = new_namearray1.capitalize
new_namearray2 = new_namearray2.join
new_namearray2 = new_namearray2.capitalize
lastarray = []
lastarray[0] = new_namearray1
lastarray[1] = new_namearray2
lastarray = lastarray.join
@aliases << lastarray
end 

loop do 
p "Give us a name"
names = gets.chomp
if names == "Quit"
    p "Thanks!"
    @aliases.each do |aliases|
    @real.each do |real|
    p "#{aliases} is actually #{real}" 
    end
    end     
break
else
    alias_machine(names)
end
end
```

Comment: You should use [`tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-tr) to substitute characters, i.e. `first_name.tr('a-z', 'ecdfighjoklmnpuqrstvawxyzb')`

Comment: @Stefan `tr` is *precisely* the tool to use here. This code is really long, confusing, and ultimately all it does is try and reimplement that.

Comment: At the very least, instead of long, sprawling chains of `if` statements, try using [`case`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-case+Expression) or a lookup table using a Hash structure. You should also remember you can often chain things together, like `n2 = n2.join.capitalize` or things like `c = [ a, b ].join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each name you append the real name and the alias to each corresponding variable. When the program quits, you iterate over the combination of both. Thus you get the exponential result.

```
@aliases.each do |aliases|
  @real.each do |real|
    p "#{aliases} is actually #{real}"
  end
end
```

You probably only want one variable with an array. You can store the pair using this command:

```
@aliases << [name, lastarray]
```

and read it again:

```
@aliases.each do |name, alias_name|
  p "#{alias_name} is actually #{name}" 
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I sort of figured it was that at the end there, but couldn't figure out how to fix it! I appreciate it.

Comment: [`alias`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/doc/syntax/miscellaneous_rdoc.html#label-alias) is a keyword, you can't use it as a variable name.